# Flutter Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

So I'm trying to show 1 of the API response but when i try my method it shows this error

```
Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.
```

My API response look like this

```
"VR": "00",
    "VALUE": {
        "dt_name": "Caramel",
        "dt_num": "20455",
        "dt_pic": "---",
    },
    "STATS": "OK",
    "LOAD": "0s"
}
```

and this is my method of getting only the name

```
Future<List<KonFirm>> _reqKonfirm() async {
    var TP = await RTUPS(name);
    var jsonData = json.decode(TP);
    var jsonName = jsonData["VALUE"];
    List<KonFirm> konfirm = [];

    for (var u in jsonName) {
      KonFirm konFirm = KonFirm(
          u["dt_name"]);

      konrirm.add(konFirm);
    }
    return konfirm;
  }
```

and Here's where I call the Data I got

```
FutureBuilder(
                    future: _reqKonfirm(),
                     builder: (BuildContext context,
                        AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                        nameController.text =
                        snapshot.data[index]
                           .dt_name;
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your jsonName contains Map and not a list
so the logical way is just to

```
KonFirm konFirm = KonFirm(
      jsonName["dt_name"]);
konfirm.add(konFirm);
return konfirm;
```

no more loop
but it would be better if you change the generic for your method to ***Future<KonFirm>*** since your json source contains only one data

Comment: so I delete the `for var u ...` and replace it to just that code?

Comment: and I return konFirm?

Comment: this happened `A value of type 'konFirm' can't be returned from the method '_reqKonfirm' because it has a return type of 'Future<List<KonFirm>>`

Answer (score 0):

the field `jsonData["VALUE"]` has only one `dt_name` property, right? then you can return the single object directly with `dt_name` property instead of lopping the map entries. Like,

```dart
Future<KonFirm> _reqKonfirm() async {
  var TP = await RTUPS(name);
  var jsonData = json.decode(TP);
  Map jsonName = jsonData["VALUE"];
  return KonFirm(jsonName["dt_name"]);
}
```

And, also you need to do some changes in your `FutureBuilder` like,

```dart
  return FutureBuilder<KonFirm>(
    future: _reqKonfirm(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<KonFirm> snapshot) {
      nameController.text = snapshot.data.dt_name;
      return;
    },
  );
```

Comment: `A value of type 'konFirm' can't be returned from the method '_reqKonfirm' because it has a return type of 'Future<List<KonFirm>>` this appears

Comment: I have modified the code snippets. Can you try it again and revert back?

Comment: @Caramel, Just change the return type of method _reqKonfirm() Future<List<KonFirm>> to Future<KonFirm>.

Comment: i did it but it doesnt seems to show anything

Comment: Make sure the `_reqKonfirm` method has return type as `Future<KonFirm>` and `FutureBuilder` widget has type as `FutureBuilder<KonFirm>` and confirm?

Comment: What would you want to show? You just return the FutureBuilder widget without doing anything. Just provide your FutureBuilder complete code for better understanding.

Comment: `FutureBuilder<KonFirm>(
                                                future: _reqKonfirm(),
                                                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<KonFirm> snapshot) {
                                                  nameController.text = snapshot.data.dt_name;
                                                });`

Comment: I wanted to show the name that have been returned

Comment: Okay Thanks, If you want to show the data in the display, you can just return the text widget with the value. Like,
FutureBuilder<KonFirm>( future: _reqKonfirm(), builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<KonFirm> snapshot) { nameController.text = snapshot.data.dt_name; return Text(snapshot.data.dt_name.toString()); });

Comment: so I want to put the return inside the Textformfield thats why I do the `nameCotroller.text = snapshot.dt_name;, so that the return of the _reqKonfirm will be inside the TextFromField, any idea how?